# "Jobs" needs an interface to exchange CV with 3rd party services - or is there any?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, profile-page

Unfortunately, there are many companies who link to some external application-flow on Jobs and there doesn't seem to be any rule for them, like the similar "no link-only answers" would suggest. Each of them would require some SO profile parser - or Stack Overflow would need to expose some API or common format. I'm more a friend of "Easy Apply", since a ping is fair enough to determine basic interest.

As a programmer I'm lazy AF, in terms of entering duplicate information, only because they fail to integrate (it doesn't look good trying to hire PHP developers and then demanding them to click through broken links/forms). Please consider the massive waste of precious time and electricity being produced by lame interaction / automation, which requires manual entry - instead of having 1 common exchange format as industry default. I don't know, but in most cases, I simply refuse to use their website, because the effort and risk of rejection - this ratio is barely balanced.

It appears as if some wanted to emulate an offline application process online ...and this is kind of bothersome (at least to me). And it is NOT meant as a rant, but only trying to explain the situation, in terms of my personal user experience.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that's not a bug, it's a feature.

> It doesn't look good trying to hire [...] developers and then demanding them to click through broken links/forms

I completely agree. Which is why, once you spot a job posting where the company links to some garbage system that wastes your time, you can use this fact to determine that the company probably isn't worth your time and look at other jobs instead.

Furthermore, what should SO even do in this case? They would need to invest a metric crapton of programmer time to interface with all the possible broken 3rd party systems, and of course that would require all 3rd party systems to offer a sensible API or a way to autofill fields. I highly doubt it would be possible in the first place, nevermind the enormous amount of effort required.